# Not able to add the record by using Custom component

Tags: sitecore-commerce

The below one is the sample component on SellableItem entity. I want to store the list of items in "Scaling Componet" section.

public class ScalingComponents : Component
    {
        public decimal Rate { get; set; } = 0.00M;
        public decimal Qty { get; set; } = 0.00M;
        public string RecordNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string RecordSeq { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }

var sampleProduct= new SellableItem
            {
                Id = productEntityId,
                ProductId = product.ProductId,
                Name = product.ProductId,
                DisplayName = product.DisplayName,
                Components = new List
                {

```
              new ScalingComponents {
                  ChildComponents = new List<Component>
                    {
                        new ScalingComponents
                        {
                            Id = random.Next().ToString(),
                            Name = "scale1" ,
                           RecordNumber="1234",
                           RecordSeq ="1111",
                           Qty=1.20m,
                           Rate=2m
                        },
                         new ScalingComponents
                        {
                            Id = random.Next().ToString(),
                            Name = "scale2" ,
                           RecordNumber="5678",
                           RecordSeq ="2222",
                           Qty=4.20m,
                           Rate=4m
                        },

                    },

                    Name ="test"
              }
            }
        };
```

This code is not inserting 2 rows in "Scaling" section in Sellable item view.
Am i missing anything here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i did the below steps and i am able to add the list of data to Custom view

1. Created "Table" type Parent EntityView
2. Added the Properties ( column names ) to the parent view
3. Created a child views with values
4. Add all child views to Parent view.

Below is the sample code.

```
 var parentView = new EntityView
                {
                    Name = context.GetPolicy<ScaleViewsPolicy>().ItemScale,
                    DisplayName = "Scales",
                    EntityId = arg.EntityId,
                    ItemId = variationId,
                    UiHint = "Table"

                };


 var childView = new EntityView
            {
                Name = "Summary",
                DisplayName = string.Empty,
                EntityId = entityView.EntityId,
                ItemId = "|" + component.RecordNumber,
            };

childView.Properties.Add(
       new ViewProperty
       {
           Name = nameof(ScalingsComponents.RecordNumber),
           RawValue = component.RecordNumber,
           IsReadOnly = isReadOnly,
           IsRequired = false,
           OriginalType = "Html",

       });

 parentView.ChildViews.Add(childView);
```